# How do I read numbers in C?

Tags: c

I have a very basic C program which I am not able to get results from. I come from the Fortran world where number crunching is straight forward and the language is non cryptic. I have gone through many C tutorials, and their treatment of processing numerical data, as opposed to strings, in C is not very comprehensive. I have tried my program on three examples data sets (integers, floats and a set of float with three variables (attached [int](http:///home/zmumba/C_Cpp_Prog_C_Progs/Data/file_in_int.txt), [floats](http:///home/zmumba/C_Cpp_Prog_C_Progs/Data/file_in_float.txt), [array](http:///home/zmumba/C_Cpp_Prog_C_Progs/Data/h900_28Mar09.txt))-Unfortunately I do not seem to be able to attach my data. 
However any example data would do. In my trial data, the first file (integers) has 10 lines of single integer value per line; file two has 10 values of a single float value per line and file three has about 3000 lines of latitude, longitude and a value per line, with a header.

The program compiles and executes, but does not give me results.
I would appreciate help

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
FILE *f;
char buff[1000],infile[16]="h900_28Mar09.txt";

f=fopen("infile","r");
fgets(buff, 26, (FILE*)f);
printf("%s\n", buff);

while (fgets(buff, 35, (FILE*)f)!=NULL)
 {
   printf("%s\n",buff);
 }
fclose(f);
}
```

[enter link description here][4]

Comment: Please show a part of your input file. You probably need `fscanf`. I suggest you start learning C from some good book or tutorial and learn the basic stuff first.

Comment: You don't need to use `(FILE *)f` everywhere. That's the type of the variable, you don't have to cast it.

Comment: And please tell us the expected output of your program.

Comment: 'I come from the Fortran world where number crunching is straight forward and the language is non cryptic' - LOL!

Comment: Just use your preferred language, C isn't it.  That infile is actually 17 chars long is, well, rough.  That you don't have to actually use 16, that takes a book.  It isn't that big btw.

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid signature, invoking undefined behaviour. The minimum signature is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *f;
  char buff[1000];

  f=fopen("h900_28Mar09.txt", "r");

  if (f == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  while (fgets(buff, 35, f) != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n",buff);
  }

  fclose(f);
}
```

This program just opens the file `h900_28Mar09.txt` and reads and display it line by line.

Alternative way:

```
...
char buff[1000], infile[] = "h900_28Mar09.txt";

f = fopen(infile,"r");
...
```

Comment: Thanks very much @
Michael Walz, you have solved my problem, that is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks also for the other comments, even discouraging ones. Thanks Michael for your time and effort and the spirit of knowledge sharing.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba-- what discouraging comments?